# Fixing a zip path vulnerability in android when reading files from asset folder but not copying it to any location

Tags: android-security

I have zipped few script files in my asset folder while building application. In run time I read those file content and convert them as String for internal usage but not copying to any location. when I upload the application in play store got **Fixing a Zip Path Traversal Vulnerability** security warning.

I think this issue is not relevant to my application, how can I communicate to play store ?

If I am wrong please help me in fixing this issue.

Thanks
Karthik